# What Pokemon can you hatch from the gift eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the recent addition of friends and giving items, also a new egg has been introduced: a 7km egg hatching new Pokemon ([source](https://pokemongolive.com/post/friendsandtrading/)). Who are these Pokemon exactly?

Answer (score 6):

There are 4 different Alolan forms of Pokemon found right now that will hatch. All of them evolve one state further. These are:

- Vulpix,
- Meowth
- Sandshrew
- Grimer

Below is a picture of the different forms and evolutions

[image: Alolan forms]

(I do not know the source of the picture, it was shared in our local telegram group)

Also, a couiple of days later, the Alolan Rattata form is also hatchable (apart from catchable in the wild).

Comment: Any idea about the distribution? I got about 20 sandshrew, 20 meowth, 2 grimer so far but not a single vulpix. Is vulpix more rare, am I doing something wrong, or am I just extremely unlucky?

Comment: @hertitu your findings are correct. Vulpix is by far the rarest, followed by grimer. I don't know about exact numbers. Unfortunately, Vulpix becomes rarer when new hatches will be added in the future